# How do you check if a user has the new timeline profile or not?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Do you get it from the user, photos, or albums table?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to determine what type of profile the current user has via the API.
A possible workaround would be to check for the presence of the 'Cover Photos' album in their list of albums, but that's not guaranteed to work, especially if that string is translated in other locales.